# Hamachi not working on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: vpn, 17.10

It seems that Hamachi is not working correctly on Ubuntu 17.10.
In particular, every invocation of `hamachi` returns:

```
Hamachi does not seem to be running.
Run '/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start' to start daemon.
```

even after running `/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi start`.
Anyone has a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Which version of Hamachi are you using exactly and how did you install it?

Comment: Version 2.1.0.174-1 for amd64. I downloaded the deb package from https://www.vpn.net/linux and installed it with `dpkg`

Comment: Could you please run `/etc/init.d/logmein-hamachi stop` and then [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo service logmein-hamachi start; sudo service logmein-hamachi status; pidof hamachid`? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hamachi version 2.1.0.174 doesn't work because it's not compatible with the newer glibc version 2.26, which is included in Ubuntu 17.10. The hamachi daemon will crash the moment you try to login with the following error:

```
hamachid: relocation error: hamachid: symbol __res_maybe_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

[See this forum post for more details](https://community.logmein.com/t5/Hamachi/Ubuntu-17-10-hamachid-crashes-on-login-glibc-2-26/td-p/141071)

I'm affraid the only way to solve this is to wait or push for LogMeIn to release a new Hamachi version that is compatible with glibc 2.26.

**UPDATE 18th January 2018:**
LogMeIn has released Hamachi for Linux beta version 2.1.0.189. This version is compatible with glibc 2.26 and can now be downloaded from https://www.vpn.net/linux

Answer (score 0):

Disabled IPv6 can also cause this problem, I suggest looking here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244076/hamachi-failing-to-install-start-on-debian-8-server

You just need to enable it on the `ham0` interface or globally in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

I had disabled IPv6 for Hadoop installation, so had this error. It just worked perfectly when I enabled IPv6.

**Check whether IPv6 is disabled OR enabled using this:**

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

*A return value of 0 means IPv6 is enabled.*

*A return value of 1 means IPv6 is disabled.*

If it's already disabled, then enable it by putting this below content in **/etc/sysctl.conf** file at the end of it. I am using the nano editor to open the file here.

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

Save and exit. Restart your system. Check the IPv6 status again.